# Visual Studio Code - Scss compiler

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code, node-sass

I would like to configure a task on VSC to compile current **scss** file in the same folder without specifying *scss* file name and *folder* name.. With **Atom** exists a package doing this..  How can I do the same with **Visual Studio Code**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use compass http://compass-style.org/

A ruby based cli tool for compiling SCSS to CSS. You have also an opportunity to set the compiled output as minified and so on...

compass has a lot of mixins for cross browser prefixes and much more features.

Comment: Thanks for your answer man but it is not what I was asking for.. I need a plugin integrated with Visual Studio Code doing that.. I'm able to compile sass file from terminal^^